# Use of undefined constant Error in Low No Spam

Tags: low, low-no-spam

I'm updating a client site to EE 2.9.2 from 2.5.1. Along the way I'm also updating the build of Low's NoSpam extension. Once installed it's throwing the following CP error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Use of undefined constant LOW_NOSPAM_CLASS_NAME - assumed 'LOW_NOSPAM_CLASS_NAME'
>   Filename: libraries/Accessories.php
>   Line Number: 106

I've re-downloaded/installed the files and uninstalled/reinstalled a couple times to no avail...

Any ideas?

Comment: The latest version of Low NoSpam doesn't have an accessory. Is the acc.low_nospam.php file still there, or is it deleted?

Comment: Yep - that was it. Thanks Low -  did I miss a note about that somewhere?

Comment: Not really, but when you update an add-on, be sure to delete the old files, instead of replacing the package, which could actually *merge* the old and new files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of Low NoSpam doesn't have an accessory. Make sure the acc.low_nospam.php file is not present in the add-on package.